# Why is my form_token missing when i'm not logged as admin?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm in charge of multiple Drupal 8 website and with some of them, the hidden field form_token is non-existent when I'm using the website anonymously.

Everything works fine when I'm logged in.

I'm sure everything was working before the quarantine but I didn't check **before updating to 8.8.6**

I tried deleting the custom twig templates of the webform and I checked my theme.theme

**webform version is 8.x-5.13** for some and 8.x-5.16 for others.

Comment: In D7 at least, tokens did not work consistently between anonymous - the initial token wouldn't match the new generated token upon submission. This may be why it doesn't exist for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the antibot module.

For some reason that I don't know, when I am not logged in, the module considers that I do not have javascrip enabled and overrides the form_token field which is required to submit the form.